# ruby- define modules dynamically

Tags: ruby, dynamic, metaprogramming

Below the sample modules (n numbers) which I am using in my project with the same method name(s) with different return value (prefix with module name).

```
module Example1
 def self.ex_method
   'example1_with_'
 end
end


module Example2
 def self.ex_method
   'example2_with_'
 end
end
```

I tried to accomplish this using metaprogramming way like #define_method. But, it's not working for me. Is there any way to do it?

```
array.each do |name|
  Object.class_eval <<TES
    module #{name}
      def self.ex_method
        "#{name.downcase}_with_"
      end
    end
  TES
end
```

**Error snap:** You could see in the last line says that it's not completed.

[image]

Comment: "Is not working" is not a good definition. What is the problem? What error messages you got?

Comment: No errors. When I tried in the `irb` the command says, still the method is not closed with end.

Why ` is not a good definition` ?

Comment: Why is it not a good definition? Because you don't give any details about error message like a stacktrace or so. 
Provide as many (relevant) details as possible so we can easily understand the problem.

Perhaps you can shed some light on WHY you want to implement something like that?

Comment: @pascalbetz explained well why it is not a good definition.

Comment: As I said, I haven't get any errors. I have updated the snap which I tried in `irb`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
m = Object.const_set("Example1", Module.new)
  #=> Example1 
m.define_singleton_method("ex_method") { 'example1_with' }
  #=> :ex_method
```

Let's see:

```
Example1.is_a? Module
  #=> true
Example1.methods.include?(:ex_method)
  #=> true
Example1.ex_method
  #=> "example1_with"
```

Answer (score 4):

***NB*: I would use the solution provided by Cary, since it’s more idiomatic.**

Now let’s answer the question as it stated in OP.

The problem is with `heredoc`

```
Object.class_eval <<TES
```

is to be closed with `TES` *in the first position*. To close as you do, use:

```
#                   ⇓ HERE
Object.class_eval <<-TES
```

Comment: Thanks. It's working. Can you tell me what is the use of `-`?

Comment: @Mr.Black: it allows some indentation for the closing identifier. http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/doc/syntax/literals_rdoc.html